# Split output of command into an associative array in bash

Tags: bash

The output is

```
/     ext4
/boot ext2
tank  zfs
```

On each line the delimiter is a space. I need an associative array like:

```
"/" => "ext4", "/boot" => "ext2", "tank" => "zfs"
```

How is this done in bash?

Comment: Not at all, unfortunately. You can't have slashes in the keys of associative arrays in bash. What is it you're ultimately trying to achieve, so I can suggest workarounds?

Comment: @Wintermute, pardon? One certainly can; the only character not valid in a key's body is NUL. Did you actually test this claim?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `arr[/]=bar` doesn't work for me with bash 4.3. Nor does anything else with `/` in it. `bash: /: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/")` is the error. Quotes don't help.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, I was being stupid, my bad. Forgot the `declare -A`/didn't remember that it was necessary. I'll go stand in the corner now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the command output is in file `file`, then:

```
$ declare -A arr=(); while read -r a b; do arr["$a"]="$b"; done <file
```

Or, you can read the data directly from a command `cmd` into an array as follows:

```
$ declare -A arr=(); while read -r a b; do arr["$a"]="$b"; done < <(cmd)
```

The construct `<(...)` is *process substitution*.  It allows us to read from a command the same as if we were reading from a file.  Note that the space between the two `<` is essential.

You can verify that the data was read correctly using `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p arr
declare -A arr='([tank]="zfs" [/]="ext4" [/boot]="ext2" )'
```

Comment: Wow this just blew my mind, I definitely need to read up on arrays.