# bash to generate bidimentional array from command output

Tags: arrays, bash, command

Using bash, I try to figure out how to fill a bidimentional array from the output of a curl command.
2 columns, but the number of line(s) is unknown.
Let's say I get names and phone numbers separated by a space.

```
$ curl ${url}
Aname 000001
Bname 123456
CCname 000887
Dnname 354632
Xname 007008
...
```

All kind of help is welcome :)
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think bash supports multidimensional arrays very well. Do you really need a 2D array or will a 1D associative array do? E.g. {Aname -> 00001, Bname -> 123456},

Comment: Thanks for your reply, well ... I guess 1D may do ....

Comment: [This may help then](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30541182/1983772)

Comment: A good question includes: input, output, sample script you tried to implement, what problem you are having.  We will not write the code for you.

Comment: Modifying my command output on the fly to look like :
`[CCname]="000887"`

And using the solution found below to create an associative array.

[bash-associative-array-with-command-output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417793/how-do-i-populate-a-bash-associative-array-with-command-output)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can test with:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A myArray
while read key value; do 
    myArray["$key"]="$value"
done <<< $( curl "$url" )

# examples to use
echo "\$myArray has ${#myArray[@]} elements"
echo "here is the keys: ${!myArray[@]}"
echo "the whole array:"
for key in ${!myArray[@]}; do
    echo "$key => ${myArray[$key]}"
done
```

for simulation, you can use:

```
...
done <<< $( cat << "END"
Aname 000001
Bname 123456
CCname 000887
Dnname 354632
Xname 007008
END
)
```

and the result will be:

```
$myArray has 5 elements
here is the keys: Aname Xname CCname Bname Dnname
the whole array:
Aname => 000001
Xname => 007008
CCname => 000887
Bname => 123456
Dnname => 354632
```